# No AddSqlServer method EntityFramework.SqlServer 7.0.0-beta8

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Trying to use the EF sql server 7.0.0-beta8 in my ASPvNext project, when trying to configure the services on startup.cs in ConfigureServices like the MVA shows I'm not presented with the .AddSqlServer() method.

I've tried rolling back to previous betas and playing with the dependencies but cant figure out whats wrong, has beta8 changed how you would do this? Below are my project dependencies.

```
  "dependencies": {
"EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
"EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8",
"Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in RC1 they renamed the package to EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/85

since everything else you have targets rc1 you should use that package instead